# DiscordJS Voice Channel Info Does Not Update

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My code:

```
// not very relevant stuff
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder
} = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {
  MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');
const tip = require('../../tips/randomtip')
const fs = require('fs')

{
  const status = require('./status')
  if(status.inUsed = true){
    status.inUsed = false
    fs.writeFileSync( './commands/music/status.json', JSON.stringify(status,null,2))
  }
}


// very relevant stuff
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('join')
  .setDescription('Join the voice channel you are in'),
  async execute(interaction) {

    const voice = interaction.member.voice
    // console.log(voice)
    console.log(voice.channel)
  },
};
```

Problem is voice.channel remains the same (I didn’t check if they are *exactly* the same, but the channel name and channel is are the same, cuz that what matters)

I’m using `discord.js` v13 latest version so don’t even question me

Comment: Which part of your code is supposed to change the channel's information?

Comment: `const voice = interaction.member.voice`
that should set constant `voice` to the channel the user is currently in
what actually happened is it shows the voice channel the user is in when the bot started and never change

Comment: It's inside a command function, it will update each time you call the command

Comment: exactly, but what happened is that it never updates

Comment: Given the code you've shown It should, given that the user changes a voice channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the problem you are having is that the `member.voice` variable does not update after the bot first starts up, the solution could be to add the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent upon Client construction.

Here is an example of how you could do this:

`const client = new Client ({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });`

Adding `intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES` should make `member.voice` update correctly when the user changes voice channel.